# Series of sed commands work on command line, but not in a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I'm working with the `.csv` output of [this SE data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/59227/unanswered-questions-that-have-a-zero-score-answer-from-the-questioner#resultSets) which looks like this (only with 5022 entries):

```
"{
  ""id"": 281952,
  ""title"": ""Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play""
}"
"{
  ""id"": 281993,
  ""title"": ""Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu""
}"
```

(And it has line `^M` endings between [number], and ""title""). I need it to look like this:

```
281952,Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play
281993,Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu
```

I fixed this in a certain text editor which shall remain nameless quite easily, but I wanted to make a script so that I don't have to do it again every time the query is refreshed & so others can use it. I used `sed`...

This series of commands works perfectly (although it may well be inefficient; it is just a trial-and-error solution):

```
# Print the ^M and remove them, write to a new file:
cat -v QueryR* | sed 's/\^M//' > QueryNew
# remove all the other junk:
sed -i 's/{//' QueryNew
sed -i 's/}//' QueryNew
sed -i 's/""//g' QueryNew
sed -i 's/^"//' QueryNew
sed -i '/,/{N;/\n.*title:\s/{s/,\n.*title:\s/,\ /}}' QueryNew
sed -i 's/^\s\+//' QueryNew
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' QueryNew
sed -i 's/^id:\ //' QueryNew
sed -i 's/,\ /,/' QueryNew
sed -i 's/\\//g' QueryNew
```

So, why doesn't this? Only the `^M` and `{}` get removed, and everything else is still there.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat -v QueryR* | sed 's/\^M//' > QueryNew
sed -i '{
       s/{//
       s/}//
       s/""//g
       s/^"//
       /,/{N;/\n.*title:\s/{s/,\n.*title:\s/,\ /}}
       s/^\s\+//
       /^\s*$/d
       s/^id:\ //
       s/,\ /,/
       s/\\//g
}' QueryNew
```

I'm sure my mistake is really obvious...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `cat -v` to turn CR characters into literal `^M` sequences seems fundamentally ugly to me - if you need to remove DOS line endings, use `dos2unix`, `tr`, or `sed 's/\r$//`'

If you insist on using sed, then I suggest you print the bits you *do* want, rather than trying to delete all the random bits you don't - for example

```
$ sed -rn -e 's/\"//g' -e 's/(.*): (.*)\r/\2/p' QueryR | paste -d '' - -
281952,Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play
281993,Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu
```

You could get fancy and roll the quote removal into the key-value extraction by matching zero or more quotes at each end of the value sequence

```
$ sed -rn 's/(.*): \"*([^"]*)\"*\r/\2/p' QueryR | paste -d '' - -
281952,Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play
281993,Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu
```

You could get *really* fancy and emulate the `paste` in `sed` by first joining pairs of lines on the `,\r$` ending and then matching the key-value pairs multiply (`g`) and non-greedily

```
$ sed -rn '/,\r$/ {N; s/([^:]*): \"*([^:"]*)\"*\r\n?/\2/gp}' QueryR
281952,Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play
281993,Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu
```

(Personally I'd favor the KISS approach and use the first one).

---

FWIW, since your input appears to be over-quoted JSON, I'd suggest installing a proper JSON parser such as `jq`

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

You can then do something like

```
$ sed -e 's/["]["]/"/g' -e 's/"{/{/' -e 's/}"/}/' QueryR | jq '.id, .title' | paste -d, - -
281952,"Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play"
281993,"Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu"
```

which removes the superfluous quotes and then uses `jq` to extract the fields of interest - note that `jq` seems to handle the DOS-style line endings, so there's no need to to take special steps to remove those.

Change to `jq '.[]'` to dump all the attribute-value pairs.

Credit for inspiration and basic `jq` syntax taken from [Overcoming newlines with grep -o](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309557/65304)

Comment: ugh yeah, idk why I forgot `\r`. `jq` broke on the first line where the title field had a colon (the first line). I am still not sure why `sed` hates me, but I killed some of the quotes and `\r` in this line `/,\r*/{N;/\n.*title.*:\s/{s/,\r*\n.*title.*:\s/,\ /}}` and finally it works like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23196488/). Thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: That's MUCH better (but I don't want any of the quotes so `sed -rn -e 's/\"\"//g' -e 's/^(.*): (.*)\r$/\2/p' QueryR* | paste -d '' - -`  & done like magic)

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it thanks to steeldriver & further tinkering. Unrefined but works.

```
sed  '{
       s/"{//
       s/}"//
       s/^"//
       /,\r/{N;/\n.*title.*:\s/{s/,\r\n.*title.*:\s/,/}}
       s/""//g
       s/^\s\+//
       /^\s*$/d
       s/^id:\ //
       s/\\//g
}' QueryR* | tee "$1"
```

translation:
`s/"{//` Remove `"{`
`s/}"//` Remove `}"`
`s/^"//` Remove `"` from start of line
`/,\r/{N;/\n.*title.*:\s/{s/,\r\n.*title.*:\s/,\ /}}` match `,\r` on one line and `[whatever]title[whatever]:` on the next line, replace all that with `,`
`s/""//g` Remove all the remaining double double quotes
`s/^\s\+//` Remove whitespace from start of lines
`/^\s*$/d` Remove empty lines
`s/^id:\ //` Remove `id:` and space after it
`s/\\//g` Remove backslashes (escape chars for " added to some title fields)
`tee "$1"` specify an outfile when running the script, for example `./queryclean newquery.csv`

Answer (score 4):

This is not exactly answering your question or solving your issue, but to get rid off the unwanted characters you can use **tr**:

```
cat QueryR | tr -d '}{:"'
```

and you'll get:

[image]

Comment: It is not as powerful as **sed** or **awk** but it is very straightforward for that kind of things. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

While the question asks for `sed`, one could work around sed's issues with Python:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
     for line in f:
         if '""id""' in line:
            print(line.strip().split(':')[1],end="")
         if '""title""' in line:
            title = " ".join(line.strip().split(':')[1:])
            print(title.replace('""'," "))
```

This code is compliant with both python2 and python3 , so either will work

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ cat questions.txt 
"{
  ""id"": 281952,
  ""title"": ""Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play""
}"
"{
  ""id"": 281993,
  ""title"": ""Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu""
}"
bash-4.3$ python3 parse_questions.py questions.txt 
 281952,  Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play 
 281993,  Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 4):

Three more approaches:

1. awk

   ```
   $ awk -F'": ' '/\"id\"/{id=$NF;} 
                 /\"title\"/{
                   t=$NF; 
                   sub(/^""/,"",t); 
                   sub(/""$/,"",t); 
                   print id,t
                 }' OFS="" file 
   281952,Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play
   281993,Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   $ perl -lne '$id=$1 if /id"":\s*(\d+)/; 
                if(/title"":\s*""(.*)""/){print "$id,$1"}' file 
   281952,Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play
   281993,Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu
   ```
3. GNU grep with perl compatible regexes and simple perl:

   ```
   $ grep -oP '(id"":\s*\K.*)|(title"":\s*""\K.*(?=""))' file | 
       perl -pe 'chomp if $.%2'
   281952,Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play
   281993,Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This is another script written in Ruby. It will retain the commas in title, which can be easily imported into any spreadsheet program without breaking the columns.

```ruby
csvfile = File.open('query-fixed.csv', 'w')

File.open('QueryResults2.csv') do |f|
    content = f.read
    content.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
    content.each_line do |line|
        id, title = '', ''
        if line.match('\"id\"')
            id = line.split(':')[1].strip[0..-2]
            csvfile.write(id + ',')
        end
        if line.match('\"title\"')
            title = line.partition(':')[2].scan(/"(.*)"/)[0][0]
            csvfile.write(title + "\n")
        end
    end
end
```

After the program is run the produced output will look like these

```
281952,"Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play"
281993,"Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu"
```

Comment: That's very nice :)

Comment: How about titles with `:` inside them?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ oops! Thanks for the pointer. Fixed now!